# Using Twilio in Disaster Recovery Application - if mobile is down will it still work with landline

Tags: twilio

If I am using Twilio for a disaster recovery application and the scenario happens that all mobile comms in a region are down but landline is still up; will Twilio still function for landline users or does it rely on mobile comms for some portion of its service?  Does Twilio rely on mobile networks for some portion of its back end?

Or should I be safe?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Twilio Customer Support here.

It depends on how you set up your application, if its primarily SMS based and the mobile network goes down in the region/country then it will impact SMS deliverability, though I cannot state 100% sure how it will affect sms to sms capable landlines.

What I recommend is you mix voice into your service on top of SMS, you could have automated messages or statements, or voicemail services.

Have you seen the Twilio.org rapid response kit? It might give you some pointers on where to look at:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/03/open-source-nonprofit-tools-twilio-org-rapid-response-kit-nt.html

Tom